# How can I authenticate a user with Devise and Android using username/password?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

The project I'm working on is an Android/Rails hybrid using Devise for authentication.  I've already got token authentication setup.

What I am not trying to figure out how to do is how to login a user via the Android device.  There is a username/password login form on the Android application.  I want it to send the username and password to the Rails application, have the Rails application authenticate the user based on these credentials, and then have the Rails application respond with this user's token.

How can I do this?  Is there a Devise method that I can pass a username and password to for authentication?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into Devise's support for HTTP Basic Authentication. This blog post describes the process for enabling it.

http://pivotallabs.com/users/ledwards/blog/articles/1534-http-basic-authentication-and-devise

Update:
Here is a detailed slide show explaining the various methods of authenticating using devise:
http://presentations.royvandewater.com/authentication-with-devise.html

Comment: I've read about how to enable HTTP Basic Authentication using config.http_authenticatable = true.  But, then, what are the next steps?  How exactly do I go about authenticating credentials passed via, let's say, an HTTP POST?

Comment: You can test it by doing something like this: curl -u user@example.com:password http://localhost:3000/users

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I just saw this, and it is working.  If I were sending the username/password combination from an Android form and POST, what should the POST parameters be?  My first guess would user[login] and user[password]. I would use user[login] because I'm allowing username authentication along with email.